# How to make electron application responsive to DPI scaling?

Tags: windows, electron, dpi-aware

I got to know that most of the legacy windows application are not automatically responsive to [DPI scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) mentioned at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

How to make electron application responsive to DPI scaling? Currently my electron application's layout is getting spoiled by changing display scale.